# Casting error with RecyclerView.ViewHolder in function onBindViewHolder

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, casting

I'm trying to display a list of item using a recyclerview holder.
Items can be displayed using two different layout.

But when I'm trying to cast my holder from RecyclerView.ViewHolder to my viewholder type, I have a casting error

(I'm trying to use recyclerview instead of listview because the way I tried, my click listener on my list item were having some kind of cache. If I displayed the first 10 elements of my list, each element had an onclicklistener logging element's position. Byt when I scroll, if I click on item 11, it was logging position 1. I've seen I might use onDetachedFromWindow to set a null listener to my item. This is what i'm trying to do with recyclerview)

My recyclerview adapter :

```java
public class WaypointArrayAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {
    private static final int CELL_TYPE_CURRENT_POS = 0;
    private static final int CELL_TYPE_WAYPOINT = 1;
    private List<Cell> cellArrayList;
    private List<Waypoint> waypointList;
    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
    private OnItemClickListener mListener;
    Context context;

    public WaypointArrayAdapter(Context context, List<Cell> cellList, List<Waypoint> waypointList) {
        layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        this.context = context;
        this.cellArrayList = cellList;
        this.waypointList = waypointList;
        setListener();
    }

    public void addItem(Cell cell) {
        cellArrayList.add(cell);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return cellArrayList.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolderOne extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements OnItemClickListener {
        public TextView currentPos;

        public ViewHolderOne(View v, final OnItemClickListener listener, final int position) {
            super(v);
            currentPos = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.currentposition);
            v.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if(listener != null) {
                        if(position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
                            listener.onItemClick(v,position);
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(View v, int position) {
           // Void
        }
    }

    public class ViewHolderTwo extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements OnItemClickListener {
        public TextView distance;
        public TextView comment;

        public ViewHolderTwo(View v, final OnItemClickListener listener, final int position) {
            super(v);
            distance = (TextView) v.findViewById((R.id.mileage));
            comment = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.comment);
            v.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if(listener != null) {
                        if(position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
                            listener.onItemClick(v,position);
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(View v, int position) {
            // Void
        }
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int position) {
        Log.d("GHT","OnCreateViewHolder");
        int type = getItemViewType(position);
        switch(type) {
            case CELL_TYPE_CURRENT_POS:
                View view1 = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.currentposition_layout, viewGroup, false);
                return new ViewHolderOne(view1,mListener,position);
            case CELL_TYPE_WAYPOINT:
                View view2 = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.waypoint_layout, viewGroup, false);
                return new ViewHolderTwo(view2,mListener,position);
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Log.d("GHT","OnBindViewHolder");
        int type = getItemViewType(position);

        switch(type) {
            case CELL_TYPE_CURRENT_POS:
                initCurrentPosLayout((ViewHolderOne)holder,position);
                break;
            case CELL_TYPE_WAYPOINT:
                initWaypointLayout((ViewHolderTwo)holder, position);
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        if (cellArrayList.get(position).getClass().getSimpleName().equals("CurrentPosition")) {
            return CELL_TYPE_CURRENT_POS;
        }
        return CELL_TYPE_WAYPOINT;
    }

    public void setListener() {
        mListener = new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(View v, int position) {
                Log.d("GHT", "Item clicked ! position = "+position);
                MainActivity.selectedId = position;
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, WaypointPopup.class);
                startActivity(context, intent,null);
            }
        };
    }

    public Cell getItem(int position) {return cellArrayList.get(position);}

    public void initCurrentPosLayout(ViewHolderOne holder, int position) {
        Log.d("GHT","InitCurrentPosLayout");
        String currentPos = "";
        if(position>0) {
            if (PointsUtils.isSnappedToTrail(getItem(position - 1), getItem(position))) {
                // On trail
                currentPos = "You are on trail km "+PointsUtils.getDistanceFormatted(waypointList.get(PointsUtils.getClosestPoint(getItem(position).getX(),getItem(position).getY(),waypointList)).getDistanceSinceBeg());
            } else {
                Waypoint closestPoint = waypointList.get(PointsUtils.getClosestPoint(getItem(position).getX(),getItem(position).getY(),waypointList));
                double distBetweenThem = PointsUtils.getDistance(getItem(position).getX(),getItem(position).getY(),closestPoint.getX(),closestPoint.getY());
                if (distBetweenThem < CLOSE_ENOUGHT_FROM_TRAIL) {
                    // close enough
                    currentPos = "You are close to trail km "+PointsUtils.getDistanceFormatted(closestPoint.getDistanceSinceBeg());
                } else {
                    // You are at XXX km of XXX trail point
                    currentPos = "You are "+PointsUtils.getDistanceFormatted(distBetweenThem)+"km away from trail km "+PointsUtils.getDistanceFormatted(closestPoint.getDistanceSinceBeg());
                }
            }
        } else {
            if (PointsUtils.isSnappedToTrail(getItem(position + 1), getItem(position))) {
                // On trail
                currentPos = "You are on trail km "+PointsUtils.getDistanceFormatted(waypointList.get(PointsUtils.getClosestPoint(getItem(position).getX(),getItem(position).getY(),waypointList)).getDistanceSinceBeg());
            } else {
                Waypoint closestPoint = waypointList.get(PointsUtils.getClosestPoint(getItem(position).getX(),getItem(position).getY(),waypointList)+1);
                double distBetweenThem = PointsUtils.getDistance(getItem(position).getX(),getItem(position).getY(),closestPoint.getX(),closestPoint.getY());
                if (distBetweenThem < CLOSE_ENOUGHT_FROM_TRAIL) {
                    // close enough
                    currentPos = "You are close to trail km "+PointsUtils.getDistanceFormatted(closestPoint.getDistanceSinceBeg());
                } else {
                    // You are at XXX km of XXX trail point
                    currentPos = "You are "+PointsUtils.getDistanceFormatted(distBetweenThem)+"km away from trail km "+PointsUtils.getDistanceFormatted(closestPoint.getDistanceSinceBeg());
                    //currentPos = closestPoint.getName()+" et "+getItem(position).getName();
                }
            }
        }
        if (!currentPos.isEmpty())
            holder.currentPos.setText(currentPos);
    }

    public void initWaypointLayout(ViewHolderTwo holder, int position) {
        Log.d("GHT","InitWaypointLayout");
        int closest = getItem(position).getId();
        if(closest>=closestId+1) {
            closest++;
        }
        int listSize = cellArrayList.size();
        double distance = PointsUtils.getTrailDistanceBetweenTwoPoints(listSize-closest-1, listSize-closestId-2, cellArrayList);
        String distanceFormatted = getDistanceFormatted(distance);
        if (!distanceFormatted.isEmpty()) {
            holder.distance.setText(getItem(position).getPrefix()+" "+distanceFormatted+"km entre "+cellArrayList.get(listSize-closest-1).getName()+" et "+cellArrayList.get(listSize-closestId-2).getName());
            String comment = "GHT km " + getDistanceFormatted(getItem(position).getDistanceSinceBeg()) + " " + getItem(position).getName();
            if (!comment.isEmpty())
                holder.comment.setText(comment);
        }

    }

}
```

My fragment :

```java
public class ByTrailList extends Fragment {
// ...
@Override
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_by_trail_list, container, false);
        waypointListView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
waypointListView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.list);

                        displayResult(location);
        }

// ...

private void displayResult(Location aLocation) {
// ...
 waypointArrayAdapter = new WaypointArrayAdapter(getContext(), cells, waypointList);
waypointListView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
            waypointListView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
            waypointListView.setAdapter(waypointArrayAdapter);
```

Error code :

```
2019-06-11 00:41:50.871 21616-21616/com.example.myapplicationtest E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.myapplicationtest, PID: 21616
    java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.myapplicationtest.WaypointArrayAdapter$ViewHolderOne cannot be cast to com.example.myapplicationtest.WaypointArrayAdapter$ViewHolderTwo
        at com.example.myapplicationtest.WaypointArrayAdapter.onBindViewHolder(WaypointArrayAdapter.java:134)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6781)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.bindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6823)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryBindViewHolderByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5752)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:6019)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5858)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5854)
        at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2230)
        at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1557)
        at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1517)
        at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:612)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3924)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:3641)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:4194)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20831)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6203)
        at android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout.onLayout(ConstraintLayout.java:1915)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20831)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6203)
        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onLayout(ViewPager.java:1775)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20831)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6203)
        at android.support.design.widget.HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.layoutChild(HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.java:142)
        at android.support.design.widget.ViewOffsetBehavior.onLayoutChild(ViewOffsetBehavior.java:41)
        at android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior.onLayoutChild(AppBarLayout.java:1556)
        at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onLayout(CoordinatorLayout.java:888)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20831)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6203)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20831)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6203)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1812)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1656)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1565)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20831)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6203)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20831)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6203)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1812)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1656)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1565)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20831)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6203)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onLayout(DecorView.java:754)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20831)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6203)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2991)
2019-06-11 00:41:50.871 21616-21616/com.example.myapplicationtest E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2504)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1635)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:7795)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:1172)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:984)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:809)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:1158)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6863)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:537)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

Comment: Well, this is the same function I was using in my previous attempt, and it was displaying perfectly. I doubt this is the issue here :/
My guess is that one holder is created with type ViewHolderOne and is being reused (cached ?) when trying to cast with type ViewHolderTwo

Comment: My bad, you might actually be right... If I return the same type every time, it doesn't crash

But when I debbug this function, it's returning the proper view...

Comment: The function is returning the correct view.
I did some debbug and logging and it does what it's meant to do

Comment: For information, OnCreateViewHolder is only called 6 times. It looks like it's not creating a new ViewHolder when trying to displays another viewholder type.

How can I fix this ? What am I missing ?

Comment: When creating the new ViewHolder, it uses position 0... I don't quite understand...
InitWaypointLayout
OnBindViewHolder
CURRENT POS : 473 ET TYPE = 1
HOLDER TYPE IS : 1
InitWaypointLayout
OnCreateViewHolder
CURRENT POS : 0 ET TYPE = 1
OnBindViewHolder
CURRENT POS : 474 ET TYPE = 0
HOLDER TYPE IS : 0